# Reload Ajax Tab with jquery UI 1.9+

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery

While their are plenty of posts regarding reloading a jQueryUI tab via the load method, I can't seem to make it work in 1.9+. I wish I could see a way to show this in a fiddle, but as I don't... note that the refresh button/function works every time in the following nested tabs set-up under 1.8+ but **works only once under 1.9+**, and fails after that. In context, (*loading dynamic content via php under wordpress*) it doesn't work **at all**.  According to the ajaxStart()ajaxStop() function calls, an ajax call is made every time the refresh button is clicked, however the content (*watch the date/time under **tab E** or tab A/sub **parent E***) is only reloaded on the first click of the #refresh button, which fails to re-load the tab content on subsequent clicks.

**stye.css**

```
div.clear { clear:both; }
#refresh {  position: relative; top:-40px; left:300px; }
#loading 
{   display:none; 
    position: absolute; 
    top:100px; 
    left:300px; 
    font-size: 200%; 
    z-index:1001; 
    border:3px solid green; 
    background:#ffffff; 
}
```

**tabs.js**

```
jQuery(function()
{   set_tabs();
    jQuery('body').on("click", "#refresh", function()
    {   jQuery('.tabset ul li a').each(function()
        {   var link = jQuery(this);
            var tab = link.parent();
            var tabset = link.closest('div.tabset');
            if(tabset.is(':visible') && tab.hasClass('ui-state-active')) index = link.text().replace(/ /g, '_');
        });
        jQuery(".tabset").tabs( "load" , index );
    });
    jQuery("#loading").ajaxStart(function() {jQuery(this).show();});
    jQuery("#loading").ajaxStop(function(){ jQuery(this).fadeOut(1500); });
});
function set_tabs()
{   jQuery('.tabset').tabs({ cache:true }); }
```

**index.html**

```
        <!--script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.16/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<link type="text/css" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.17/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet"-->
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.9.2/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<link type="text/css" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.9.2/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script type="text/javascript" src="tabs.js"></script>
<link type="text/css" href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div id="parentTabSet" class="tabset">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#A">A</a></li>
        <li><a href="#B">B</a></li>
        <li><a href="#C">C</a></li>
        <li><a href="#D">D</a></li>
        <li><a href="tabs_e.html">E</a></li>
    </ul>
    <input type='button' id='refresh' value='refresh' />
    <div id='loading'>Loading...</div>
    <div id="A" class="tabset">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#A_1">A_1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#A_2">A_2</a></li>
            <li><a href="tabs_e.html">parent E</a></li>
        </ul>
        <div id="A_1"><p>A_1 - FOO</p></div>
        <div id="A_2"><p>A_2 - BAR</p></div>
    </div>
    <div id="B"><p>Div B</p></div>
    <div id="C"><p>Div C</p></div>
    <div id="D"><p>Div D</p></div>
</div>
```

**tabs_e.html**

```
<script>
jQuery( function()
{   set_tabs();
    var d = new Date();
    jQuery('#E_1 p').text(d);
    jQuery('#E_2 p').text(d);
});
</script>
<div class="tabset">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#E_1">E_1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#E_2">E_2</a></li>
    </ul>
    <div id="E_1"><p>E_1 - BAR</p></div>
    <div id="E_2" class='clear'><p>E_2 - BAZ</p></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The `.live()` function has been deprecated for a while now, and support is completely gone in jQuery 1.9+.  Use this:

```
$(document).on("click", "#refresh", function() {
      // your current "live" code
});
```

Comment: Yeah... little by little I've been switching out all my live calls for on, but just for grins I went ahead and switched it out here and that's not the problem.  Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

So it turns out that not only has the [cache option been deprecated](http://jqueryui.com/upgrade-guide/1.9/#deprecated-ajaxoptions-and-cache-options-added-beforeload-event) in 1.9+ it's legacy behavior has been altered such that (if used) the load method will not reload the tab content.
The approach I've come up with is -- I think -- an abomination which I'm hoping some one might provide a cleaner alternative to. (oh pleeeaazzz!) Anyway, FWIW... here's what I came up with.

**tabs.js** (revisited)

```
jQuery(function()
{   set_tabs();
    jQuery(document).on("click", "#refresh", function()
    {   refresh = {};
        refresh.tab = true;
        jQuery('.tabset ul li a').each(function()
        {   var link = jQuery(this);
            var tab = link.parent();
            var tabset = link.closest('div.tabset');
            if(tabset.is(':visible') && tab.hasClass('ui-state-active')) index = link.text().replace(/ /g, '_');

        });
        jQuery(".tabset").tabs( "load" , index );
    });
    jQuery("#loading").ajaxStart(function() {jQuery(this).show();});
    jQuery("#loading").ajaxStop(function(){ jQuery(this).fadeOut(1500); });
});
function set_tabs()
{   jQuery('.tabset').tabs(
    {   beforeLoad: function( event, ui)
        {   if(typeof refresh.tab =='undefined')
            {   if ( ui.tab.data( "loaded" ))
                { event.preventDefault();
                    return;
                }
                ui.jqXHR.success(function() {   ui.tab.data( "loaded", true );});
            }   else refresh={};
        }
    });
}
```